# How to save content?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I try to save multilanguaged content in model. I have two models

PostLang

```
class PostLang extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
       {

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'postlang';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['post_id', 'lang_id', 'title', 'content'], 'safe'],
        [['post_id', 'lang_id'], 'integer'],
        [['title', 'content'], 'string'],
        [['post_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Post::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['post_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}
...
  public function getPost()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Post::className(), ['id' => 'post_id']);
}
  }
```

and Post

```
   class Post extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
         public static function tableName() {
    return 'post';
}

public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'timestamp' => [
            'class' => 'yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior',
            'attributes' => [
                \yii\db\ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['date_create', 'date_update'],
                \yii\db\ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['date_update'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}


public function rules() {
    return [
        [['status', 'date_update', 'date_create'], 'integer'],
        [['date_update', 'date_create'], 'safe'],
    ];
}   
   ...
public function getPostlangs() {
    return $this->hasMany(Postlang::className(), ['post_id' => 'id']);
}
```

}

i created a PostController with create method

```
 public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Post();
    $post_ru = new PostLang();
    $post_en = new PostLang();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($model->save()) {

            $dbPost = new PostLang();
            $dbPost->title = need to save title;
            $dbPost->content = need to save content;
            $dbPost->lang_id = need to save lang_id;
            $dbPost->post_id = $model->id;
            $dbPost->save();
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I need to save it in foreach but i don't understand how  can i do it. 
Form

```
...
<?= $form->field($post_ru, 'title')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($post_ru, 'content')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($post_en, 'title')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($post_en, 'content')->textInput() ?>
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You should separate models in your activeForm,because only last model will save.

Form:

```
<?= $form->field($post_ru, "[0]title")->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($post_ru, "[0]content")->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($post_en, "[1]title")->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($post_en, "[1]content")->textInput() ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Post();
    $post_ru = new PostLang();
    $post_en = new PostLang();
    $postData = Yii::$app->request->post('PostLang');
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($model->save()) {
            $post_ru->load($postData[0]);
            $post_en->load($postData[1]);
            if ($post_ru->save()) {
                $post_ru->link('post', $model);
            }
            if ($post_en->save()) {
                $post_en->link('post', $model);
            }
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Don`t forget to +rep,if it was useful.

Comment: getting an error on `if ($post_ru->save()) {`     "Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`asur`.`postlang`, CONSTRAINT `lang-to-post` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)"

Comment: Go to yii2 debug toolbar and select db tab. There are will be sql request that fails.Send me,i`ll check.